# Prove that $H=\{a+b{\bf i} : a,b \in\mathbb Z\}$ is not cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Let **i=** $\sqrt{-1}$ **$\in$** **Complex Numbers** and **H=**$\{$a+b**i** : a,b $\in$ Z$\}$. Show that H is not cyclic. The operation is (Complex Numbers(C),+).

In my opinion,

Suppose, (C,+) is cyclic.

Then , there exist a **x** $\in$ C s.t  $\lt$x$\gt$= C.

Note, x=a+bi

Note, C=$\lt$x$\gt$=$\{$n.x : n $\in$ N$\}$

Note, (1/2)x $\in$ C ,but (1/2)x is not element of $\lt$x$\gt$. If it were, (1/2)x = nx for some n $\in$ N

Note, 1/2=n a contradiction.

Hence, (C,+) is not cyclic.

Is this proof correct ? I'm confused about we can choose a,b $\in$ Z.

If this proof whether true or not could you please give an another proof of this?

Comment: You seem to be conflating $C$ and $H$.  The former consists of the numbers $a+bi$ for all real numbers $a,b$; the latter consists of $a+bi$ only for integers $a,b$.  One can prove that $C$ isn't cyclic, and one can also prove, with a different argument, that $H$ isn't cyclic, but you seem to be mixing together parts of those two proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $H$ is cyclic with generator $z = a+bi$.

Note that $i = 0+i \in H$. Thus, if $H$ is cyclic, $i = na + (nb)i$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z^+$. This leads to:

$na = 0, nb = 1$.

Since $n \neq 0$, we must have $a = 0$ (because $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain). Since $nb = 1$, we must have $b = 1$ (since $n > 0$).

But $1 = 1 + 0i \in H$, as well, and $mi = 1$ has no solutions for $m \in \Bbb Z^+$.